# Terminal L in C

Tags: c, variables

In C, are the following equivalent:

`long int x = 3L;` (notice the `L`)

and

`long int x = 3`

They seem to be the same. In case they are, which one should be used? Should the `L` be specified explicitly?

If they are different, what is the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`3.14L` is a `long double` literal, while `3.14` is a `double` literal. It won't make much difference in this case, since both are being used to initialize a long int. The result will be 3.

EDIT:
Ok, `3L` is a `long` literal, while `3` is an `int` literal. It still won't make much difference, since the `int` will be "promoted" to a long. The result will be the same in both cases.

EDIT 2:
One place it might make a difference is something like this:

```
printf("%ld\n", 123);
```

This is undefined behavior, since the format string specifies a `long` and only an `int` is being passed. This would be correct:

```
printf("%ld\n", 123L);
```

Comment: My main question is, since I have specified that `x` is `long int`, is it necessary to write the `L` or I should let the `long int` part take care of it?

Comment: @A A: It's not necessary here. There are other times when it might be necessary. But you can let type promotion do its thing here.

Comment: @Fred: Sorry for nitpicking, but can you give me an example as to where it will matter?

Comment: I am asking because I want to know if `L` should be specified explicitly or not.

Comment: You might also need the `L` to write things like `1L<<20` in a portable way (since `1` might be just 16-bit, giving `1<<20` undefined behavior).

Answer (score 1):

A decimal integer constant without suffix has - depending on its value - the type `int`, `long`, `long long`, or possibly an implementation-defined extended signed integer type with range greater than `long long`.

Adding the `L` suffix means the type will be at least `long`, the `LL` suffix means that the type will be at least `long long`.

If you use the constant to initialize a variable, adding a suffix makes no difference, as the value will be converted to the target-type anyway. However, the type of the constant may well be relevant in more complex expressions as it affects operator semantics, argument promotion and possibly other things I didn't think of right now. For example, assuming a 16-bit `int` type,

```
long foo = 42 << 20;
```

invokes undefined behaviour, whereas

```
long bar = 42L << 20;
```

is well-defined.